# Algebra Linear Transformations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, plane-curves

Hi I have a question which I don't really understand and wondered whether I could get some help on it.

Question:

Write the standard matrices representing the following linear transformations in the plane $R^2$:

$T_1:$ a  reflection through the x-axis,

$T_2:$ an anti-clockwise rotation by $\theta$.

Hence find a value of $\theta$ satisfying $0 < $ $\theta$ $<$ $π$, for which $T_1$ $\circ$ $T_2$ $=$ $T_2$ $\circ$ $T_1$?

Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: That is not a question.

Comment: Ok, but i need help on writing the standard matrices and finding the value of theta....

Comment: I don't really see how stating "that is not a question" could be of any help to anyone.

Comment: @TheStatistician Well, it may help **you** to realize you've asked at least three different questions. Can you do some of them and then ask about details you need?

Comment: I've tried but I don't actually understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I answer you one part of your question, you try the others...perhaps going over your notes first:

$$T_1\binom xy=\binom x{-y}\implies [T_1]=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, you should make an effort to understand (1) why the above definition of $\;T_1\;$ is the correct one, and (2) why the above matrix represents $\;T_1\;$ wrt the standard basis.

Once you've done the above, try the rest of your question. If you get stuck write back...

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll give $T_2$ a go now and see what i can get from your explanation.  I'll write back with what I've got and see if that's the correct solution .